# View source does not display dynamic content in angular universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

My angular app, which is an ssr, calls an API to get the product name, then I display it in the H1 tag like below

```
<h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
```

but When I check my view source page (ctrl + u ) the  tag is empty.
I think It is because SSR creates html template without waiting for API call.
the Problem is:
"When ssr sends me html, I want to make sure the h1 tag is not empty so that a crawler can find it for SEO purposes."
I search about it but cant find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is your angular app a PWA? Then this would be normal.

Is the page SSR'ed when you do <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. Then everything is okay, and you don't have to worry.

Otherwise, there's a big chance that your production server doesn't allow webrequests during SSR, and you will need to use something equivalent to the `SupplyData` method in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Stuck with the same... Any solution ??

Comment: Hmm, in case you're using .NET Core 3.1, your `SupplyData` delegate cannot be async. SupplyData is not being awaited in the Microsoft source code